# Expo React Native Can't find variable: TextDecoder

Tags: react-native, expo

So for some reason i'm having this bug when i try to run the app on the Expo Go app in my phone. Apparently is ok if i run on the web browser.

This is the error log

ReferenceError: Can't find variable: TextDecoder

> Stack trace:
> node_modules\expo\build\environment\react-native-logs.fx.js:27:4 in
> error
> node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\ExceptionsManager.js:95:4 in
> reportException
> node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\ExceptionsManager.js:141:19
> in handleException
> node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\setUpErrorHandling.js:24:6 in
> handleError
> node_modules@react-native\polyfills\error-guard.js:49:36 in
> ErrorUtils.reportFatalError
> node_modules\metro-runtime\src\polyfills\require.js:203:6 in
> guardedLoadModule
> http://192.168.0.29:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&strict=false&minify=false:190345:3
> in global code   ...

Comment: Were you able to solve it? The same happens to me when running on Expo. Browser works fine, Expo Go is broken. I think it has to do with a dependency or a AppRegistry.Component.

Comment: I did not! What i did was start another project and just copy everything hahaha. I got exausted from searching it so i just started it all over again.

Comment: Are you using expo in your new project or just react native? It's so frustrating hahaha

Comment: Using Expo. Indeed it's sooooo frustrating. To just spend hours searching for how to fix bugs hahaha

Answer (score 5):

The reason it's working for you on the web but not on the phone is because `TextDecoder` is a web API that's [generally available](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TextDecoder#browser_compatibility) in all modern **browsers** JS engines but it is not supported on Hermes (React Native's JS engine). The way to fix the issue is to use a polyfill for the API and expose it globally.

One simple way to achieve this is to use this [polyfill library](https://github.com/acostalima/react-native-polyfill-globals).
Another way is to mimic what that library does which gives you more flexibility to choose what polyfill to use as there are many options to choose from (see the competitors list [here](https://github.com/anonyco/FastestSmallestTextEncoderDecoder#benchmarks) for example). To do this you'll need to install the polyfill of your choice (e.g. `npx expo install text-encoding`) and then create a file with the following content:

```js
import { polyfillGlobal } from "react-native/Libraries/Utilities/PolyfillFunctions"

const applyGlobalPolyfills = () => {
  const { TextEncoder, TextDecoder } = require("text-encoding")

  polyfillGlobal("TextEncoder", () => TextEncoder)
  polyfillGlobal("TextDecoder", () => TextDecoder)
}

export default applyGlobalPolyfills
```

then import this file in your `App.js` file (or your root `_layout.js` if using Expo's Router v2) and call the exported function like so:

```js
import applyGlobalPolyfills from "path/to/applyGlobalPolyfills" // <-- Change the path
applyGlobalPolyfills()

// ...rest of App.js file
```

Probably worth noting that you can add any other global API you need support for this way. You can either add it to the same file or split it up to different util functions per global API for tree shaking, etc.

Comment: Great answer. TIL about polyfillGlobal

Answer (score 2):

This happened to us too, on an app that had used to work in an older Expo version. The solution for us was to add this line to our `.babelrc.js` file:

```js
"presets": [
  ["babel-preset-expo", {
    lazyImports: true, // <<< The fix
  ]
]
```

Comment: Can you explain why this works, and where this variable comes from? Thanks!

Comment: I don't know why it works, you'd have to ask the Expo or React Native team, but `TextDecoder` is a JS global attached to the `window` object like `window.TextDecoder`. I discovered this fix by comparing our working config before an upgrade with our broken config after an upgrade.

Comment: I'm not familiar with [`lazyImports: true`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-preset-expo/v/9.0.0#lazyimports) but my guess is that you should be careful with it as you may just be rolling the issue down the line. I suspect some dependency of yours is calling the `TextDecoder` API at some point and lazily evaluating it pushes the error from init to when the API is actually used. I think you should consider adding the polyfill as suggested [above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76791074/2278329) to avoid issues.

Comment: The `lazyImports` suggestion is specifically because it's what was required for the specific  fix necessary when something changed in Expo and broke existing projects. Polyfills are fine, but this is the "correct" solution if you're upgrading legacy Expo projects.

Answer (score 1):

Got over the problem by doing this;

`npm install text-encoding`

`npm install big-integer`

and pasting this code inside node_modules>react-native>Libraries>LogBox

```
const TextEncodingPolyfill = require('text-encoding');
const BigInt = require('big-integer')
Object.assign(global, {
  TextEncoder: TextEncodingPolyfill.TextEncoder,
  TextDecoder: TextEncodingPolyfill.TextDecoder,
  BigInt: BigInt,
});
```

Comment: If anyone is wondering, what worked for me is the LogBox.js file